# How to encrypt android device without screen lock?

Tags: security, lock-screens, encryption

I want to encrypt my phone to protect sensitive information. But I do not want to enter a password every time I pick up my phone. That seriously hampers the usability. Particularly because the password must be of sufficient complexity for the encryption to be secure.

What I want is a boot time only password.

Most thieves switch off the phone after stealing it. Or remove the battery to change the SIM (so it won't get tracked). When he starts it again it'll be locked. There is a risk that he may mail my sensitive information to himself before switching off the phone but that is a risk I'm willing to live with.

How do I encrypt my phone with only a boot time password?

Comment: Cyanogenmod has this exact feature

Comment: Set up encryption normally, then disable the lock screen via an app such as No Lock: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jraf.android.nolock (Better test the app before encrypting,  try the different no-lockscreen apps to see which one works with your phone model)

Comment: @Colin: Cyanogenmod does not have such a feature. You are forced to use a PIN or a password after encryption. It might be achievable with some tools but it does not work out of the box, even for Cyanogenmod.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known defect.

See this [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29468) report. And this discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-security-discuss/FzngJnjhS5g) at google groups.

Answer (score 0):

All you need (private space, anti-theft and much more):

[Comodo Mobile Security](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.comodo.pimsecure&hl=en)

Also you can use Android built-in encryption which asks for password only on boot:

Settings ➡ Security ➡ Encrypt

Comment: The built-in encryption option asks for lock screen password to be set before encryption can be done.

Comment: Personally never used it since entire home partition would be encrypted and has performance penalty. For small size of sensitive data use 'EDS Lite'.